# “It would have been best written in a more concise way as it does tend to ramble.” meaning

Tags: sentence-meaning

> It would have been best written in a more concise way as it does tend to ramble.

I came across this sentence in [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ramble). I'm not sure what the sentence is trying to convey. The author uses the conjunction word **as** to connect the two clauses "*It would have been best written in a more concise way*" and "*it does tend to ramble*". But the two seem to be irrelevant. I am kind of lost here. Any thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also write:

> It would have been best written in a more concise way **because** it does tend to ramble.

*would have been* implies an expectation (written in a more concise way), which is followed by an opinion/reasoning why the expectation was not met (it tends to ramble).

You can't use *if* because the if/then format implies a more factual cause and effect. For example:

> I won't buy the book **if** the topic discussed doesn't stay focused.

Comment: I see what you meant, but that connection is still odd to me. "It does tend to ramble" is the fact we get, it doesn't sound a good reason for writing it in a more concise way. It seems to make more sense to me if the sentence is written as "*It would have been best written in a more concise way if it didn't tend to ramble*".

Comment: I edited my explanation.

Comment: But, @Dan, if it didn't ramble, it would already be concise.